# Systematic Random Sample - Teradata SQL Ast

Tags: random, teradata

I need to produce a systematic random sample of (approx) 2500 rows from (approx)230,000 rows with a unique auto generated number on each row.

Is this possible using Teradata SQL ast? (The Sample function produces a simple random sample.)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The Sample function produces a **simple** random sample. How do you define the *systematic* part?

Comment: Yes, it does produced a simple random sample. The point of my question - but I guess I had systematic on my brain! The systematic sample is an interval sample. I need to select a random start (simple random sampling) and then select rows at intervals of 2500. So for example: If my random start is  row number 1000 then I would select row number 3500, then row number 6000, then row number 8500 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
select rank() over(order by $primary_index_key), t1.*
FROM 
(select * from $table_name
sample 2500) t1
```

Assistant would do that, and so would any other client.
Same approach can be used to generate winning Powerball numbers.

Comment: I may be missing something but I think that would provide me with a simple random sample rather than a systematic one.

Answer (score 1):

When there's already a gapless unique row number:

```
select t.*
from mytable as t
cross join
 ( select random(1,2500) as rnd ) as dt -- random start row
where rownumber mod 2500 = rnd          -- every 2500 rows
```

Otherwise ROW_NUMBER can be used to create it:

```
select t.*
from mytable as t
cross join
 ( select random(1,2500) as rnd ) as dt
qualify ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY whatever_determines_your_order) mod 2500 = rnd
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I think that you cannot do it on the fly. You need to generate some table first that would contain Step# and step_value, for example:

[1,2500],[2,5000],...[x,x*2500]

Than you should join this table to your query and limit row numbers by the logic: rn = random_seed + step_value.
It will look like this:

```
select
from (
 select t1.*
 , row_number() over("ordering logic") as rn
 from my_table
) as t1
, (select random(1,2500) as random_seed) as seed --so it will be generated only once

where exists (
   select 1 from sampling_table as t2
   where t1.rn = t2.step_value + seed.random_seed
  )
```